# Payment tables design

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I have 2 tables Payments and PaymentMethods. However depending on the payment method, some card details won't be stored and some extra details may. So the card details stored depend on the payment method - for example with wire transfer. What is the best way to design this?

```
+--------------+
| Payments     | 
+--------------+
| CardDetails  |
| Amount       |
| OtherDetails |
+--------------+

+---------------+
| PaymentMethods|
+---------------+
| Id            |
| Type          |
+---------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are dealing with Supertype\Subtype problem. All payments have something in common (at least ID and Type), but every type has some unique attributes. You can model this scenario in several ways, each with pros and cons.

'Classical' solution is to put supertype in one table (Payment) and create separate table for every subtype (way of payment). There is 1:1 relation between supertype table and every subtype table.

Example, supertype table:

> Payment (**PaymentID**, PaymentMethodID, Date, UserID ...)

Subtypes:

> CreditCardPayment(**PaymentID**, CardNumber, ....)
>
> PayPalPayment(**PaymentID**, SecurityCode, ...)
>
> WireTransfer(**PaymentID**, AccountNumber, ...)

When you create payment, you create record in Payment and record in one of subtypes in one transaction. This way of implementation is a good one because it is normalized, can be easily extended and error-proof. But unfortunately it is very verbose and take more efforts then de-normalized solution.

De-normalized solution is to create one Payment table and add bunch of columns for all payment methods. When you create new payment, most of columns are nulls and only application logic knows what columns should be defined. This solution is much simpler in implementation, but has obvious problems.

There are more options for special cases but I think they are overkill for a payment system. So it is your call, what to choose. As a DB man, I'd prefer first option.